# install svn client on redhat RHEL5

Tags: linux, svn, installation, redhat

How do I install svn on a Redhat machine?

Tried to do it with `yum install svn` - but it didn't find svn.

My machine details are

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)

Found it with this command
/etc/redhat-release

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
yum install subversion
```

Comment: I am getting `No package subversion available.`

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito Try "updatedb" or "yum update"
Then "yum install subversion"